# Webbrowser C# How to put a changing value in a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I cant seem to figure out how to put the value text into a texbox.Text on Webbrowser C# because with this website the value changes and there are duplicates of the input code and cant pinpoint Webbrowser to put the changing value username in a textbox.Text as seen in screenshot below.

I hope someone knows how to do this with the Webbrowser in C#
Thanks in advance.

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvXwO.png)

This is the website I am trying to get the username from: [fakepersongenerator](http://www.fakepersongenerator.com/Index/generate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to manually scan through the DOM and find the element based on it's xpath. Like this:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) =>
{
    var frame1 = webBrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByClassName("frame-1");
    if (frame1.Count > 0)
    {
        var rows = frame1[0].GetElementsByClassName("row no-margin");
        if (rows.Count > 4)
        {
            var usernameForm = rows[4].GetElementsByClassName("form-control");
            if (rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Do something with value here
                Console.WriteLine(usernameForm[0].GetAttribute("value"));
            }
        }
    }
};
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.fakepersongenerator.com/Index/generate");
```

Extension class to :

```
internal static class Utils
{
    internal static List<HtmlElement> GetElementsByClassName(this HtmlElement doc, string className = "")
    {
        var list = new List<HtmlElement>();
        foreach (HtmlElement e in doc.All)
            if (e.GetAttribute("className") == className)
                list.Add(e);
        return list;
    }
}
```

There isn't really a way in the default web browser to detect changes after a page load, so if you wanted to monitor for changes, you'd have to set up a `BackgroundWorker` or `Timer` to poll the browser and manually look for a value change.

Comment: Thank you, How would you make an Extension class to implement it into the code without errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If this worked for you, can you select is as best answer?